# Problem with a recursive function (check if a number is a perfect square)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to write, in CodeBlocks, a recursive function that check if a natural number (a long double) is a perfect square. This function called "Square" takes in input, by reference, the long double S and n (setted in the beginning at 1), a bool T and the long double to compare.

Here the code:

```
void Square(long double& S, long double& n, bool& T,long double k){
        S=S+2*n+1;
        n++;
        if(S==k){
             T=true;
        }

        if(S>k){
            T=false;

        }

        if(S<k){
            Square(S,n,T,k);
        }
}
```

And in the main function:

```
long double S,n,k;

bool T=false;

for(long double b=1;b<50000;b++){

    for(long double a=1;a<b;a++){

        S=1;
        n=1;
        T=false;

        k=12*a*b*b*b-3*a*a*a*a;

        Square(S,n,T,k);

        if(T==true){
            cout<<a<<"    "<<b<<"   "<<k<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes occours this error: "Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)" (for example when (a = 108 and b = 121) and the program stops. Any help?

Comment: "Sometimes"? Consistently? For what input? We like [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: You're relying on exact equality of floating-point numbers. That's a bad idea and often goes wrong. When it goes wrong, you probably get a ... stack overflow

Comment: @Useless: long double has a very big precision: it can't be an overflow.

Comment: And: stack overflow is not floating-point overflow. It means your recursion doesn't terminate in a reasonable number of levels.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this error?

Comment: 1/ Don't use floating point. Or 2/ decide on the level of precision you really need, choose an appropriate value for `epsilon`, and use the expression I already showed you. Oh, and it might be worth reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/212858) other question for background.

Comment: Handy reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Recommended reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) , [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5910058) , [Sometimes Floating Point Math is Perfect](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2017/06/19/sometimes-floating-point-math-is-perfect/) . Please read and comprehend all 3, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <cmath>

bool isPerfectSquare( long num ) {
    long root = long(sqrt(float(num)));
    return root * root == num;
}
```

You'll get `True` if `num` is a perfect square or `False` if not.

Comment: Error: 'root' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Error: expected ',' or ';' before 'return'

Comment: sorry for syntax, i'm writing python code most of the time

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting a stack overflow error (which is when you use up the entirety of a thread's stack, and it crashes). If you compile with optimizations enabled, the compiler should be able to optimize `Square` so that it's tail-recursive, which will prevent the stack overflow error.

That being said, we can make `Square` shorter and friendlier to optimization by removing the references, and just calculating the multiplication directly (which is very cheap):

```
bool is_square(long long k, long long n = 0) {
    if(n * n >= k)
        return n * n == k;
    else
        return is_square(k, n + 1);
}
```

With optimization turned on (use the `-O2` compiler flag for gcc and clang, or `/Ox` for msvc), [**this compiles to a simple loop**](https://godbolt.org/z/JTXV9s):

```
is_square(long long, long long):
        mov     rax, rsi
        imul    rax, rsi
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jle     .L3
.L2:
        add     rsi, 1
        mov     rax, rsi
        imul    rax, rsi
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jl      .L2
.L3:
        cmp     rdi, rax
        sete    al
        ret
```

#### Fast solution using `cmath` library:

```
#include <cmath>

bool is_square(long long k) {
    long double real_root = sqrt((long double)k); 
    long long integral_root = llround(real_root);
    return integral_root * integral_root == k;
}
```

Comment: should not use a recursion where a simple loop will suffice

Comment: It compiles to a loop, and the asker seemed to want to do things recursively